# c# generics, passing class

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics, interface

I just can't figure out how to write an equivalent interface in c#.

Java:

```
public interface DAO {
    <T> T find(Class<T> c, Object key);

    <T> List<T> get(Class<T> c);

    <T> void persist(T object);
}
```

This is my attempt so far in c#, problem is i need the Class to call the  `dataclassesdatacontext.GetTable<Class here>().ToList();`:

```
interface IDAO
{
    T Find<T>(object key);

    List<T> Get<T>(T c);

    void Persist<T>(T obj);
}
```

I want to implement it like this:

`public List<T> Get<T>()
        {
            return _dbx.GetTable<T>().ToList();
        }`

where _dbx is the dataclassdatacontext (linq to sql). 
But i get a red line under T which says: 
The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter.

Comment: Your interface looks ok, except for the `Get<T>` method (I don't see the purpose in passing an instance of T to that method, it should probably just be `Get<T>()`). Where do you find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are [Generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). Namely you need to add `where T : class` to methods with T parameter.

And like Darin Dimitrov said, it might be good idea to set type for whole interface, not every method. This will result in cleaner desing.

Answer (score 4):

The generic parameter could be placed on the interface definition:

```
public interface IDAO<T>
{
    T Find(object key);
    List<T> Get(T c);
    void Persist(T obj);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear the the `Get` method should have a parameter. I think it's supposed to mean "Get all objects of type T".

Comment: @Gabe, correct, it should probably be some other object. Unfortunately the OP didn't provide enough information about his scenario so we can only be guessing.

Comment: Sorry. But you are right. The end result of the Get method should be to get all objects in database of a certain class. The find should find an object of the specified class with the specified key

Comment: If i do it this way i need to implement the interface for each class i have in the db.